# android - import - with developers google com games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm follow the guide here  https://developers.google.com/games.
I did all the insturction in step 1 ("Step 1: Download the sample app") but the project isn't compile.

after I imported the  google-play-services-lib project and the BaseGameUtils project, their R.java file appear in gen directory.

In the lines:

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.Player;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
```

I get the errors :

```
The import com.google.android.gms.games cannot be resolved
The import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity cannot be resolved
```

What could be the problem.

This is how the project look now:
**Edit 1:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

[image]

**Edit 3:**

[image]

Comment: you should refer to the library project have you done that?

Comment: how did you do it can you elaborate something night be wrong

Comment: exacly like step 1.4 in the link : 
Make sure that the Google Play services and BaseGameUtils library projects are referenced in your Android project. To do this in Eclipse:
Right-click your Android project and select Properties > Android.
In the Library section, add the google-play-services-lib project and the BaseGameUtils project, then click OK to save.

Comment: right click properties choose android and check if your libray is referenced and you do have a green tick for the same

Comment: look at the picture in my second update. I think the refernce is ok

Comment: seems all right just clean and build should work finw

Comment: I try it more than once..

Comment: are the library project and your android project in the same workspace same folder?

Comment: It has to be under the same folder? I mean, if my game is called TAN like in the picture , I need to put it and BaseGameUtils project under the same directory?

Comment: no i said it has to be in the same workspace. same folder where you have your android project. not under the same directory

Comment: yes they are under the same folder

Comment: I added another picture than my be helpful

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40194/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user1932595)

Answer (score 2):

You probably did not reference google_play_services in your BaseGameUtils library. Right click the BaseGameUtils. Select Properties > Android. Add the google-play-services-lib project. Click okay to save.