# error when import google play services lib

Tags: android, google-play-services

I follow the instruction here https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

The project lib is now appear in my eclipse but I have error :

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: pls follow http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. and don't duplciate questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655133/android-import-with-developers-google-com-games

Comment: I relize that my previous question is wrong because the problem is here. And as I wrote, i follow this link and get the problem as in the picture

Comment: just a suggestion check if android private libraries is checked in order export tab

Comment: Sorry if I am mistaken where these jar files are located but, couldn't you add these jar files to your lib folder and add them to the build pat that way? Or are these jar files not accessible

Comment: I checked again the project and I suprisngly see the jar file and jar.properties file isn't exist - so appearntly this is the problem. But why it isn't there??

Comment: I download the jar file manually and add it. But I can't find the other file in the internet (google-play-services.jar.properties)...

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with importing google play services library. Here is what I did...

1. Delete the library, on your eclipse AND on your computer.
2. Download a fresh, up to date revision of google play services library and save it in your preferred directory.
3. Go to your eclipse, file, import, existing code, navigate to the directory of the library, OK.
4. Now that the library is in your eclipse, right click your project (not the library, your app project) and click properties, under android, click add, click the library you just imported, click apply, and then you should be done.