# BaseGame Util cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-games

my project requires BaseGameUtil library
I have BaseGameUtil library downloaded form [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples)

But when i import it in my android project it doesnt show baseGameUtil instead it shows main as added in my eclipse project and even when i add that main library i still get the same error.

> Can anyone help me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you have to add it to your project build path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BaseGameActivity cannot be resolved to a type

public Class FisrstActivity extends BaseGameActivity{
```

- In your project, right click > `properties` > `Android` > in `Library` section check if your library is correct and don´t show any red cross.
- Check the same for your `BaseGameUtils` library, probably the reference to `google_play_services` is incorrect.

you problem must be similar to : [android - import - with developers google com games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655133/android-import-with-developers-google-com-games)

Comment: i have tried but not working. i have added a picture of my properties->android picture. where i am adding library. there are no errors .

Comment: delete the "com.google.example." from that import line

Comment: Thanks i resolved the issue . there was another file of BaseGameUtil that i had to import

Comment: what was the other file?

Comment: I had 2 folders of baseGameUtil., when you will download GooglePlayService library you will get a folder of BaseGameUtil . or try to import parent folder so all project/lib will import to eclipse and then try which you need

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be using the version of BaseGameUtils in here:

...\android-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries

But you are using Eclipse so you need to use the one in the following location:

...\android-samples-master\eclipse_compat\libraries

You may then also encounter an error with the GameHelper.java class in the BaseGameUtils folders. Use the code available here instead: https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

Comment: fixed. with your guide and BaseGameActivity located here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit

Answer (score 0):

Basegameutils from github includes all source .java files in java folder. When implementing in eclipse, move all these folders from 'java' to 'src'. Eclipse compiles them to produce .class files which fixes this problem.