# Resolve BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

as many people I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) without success.
The simple error is:

```
The import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity cannot be resolved
```

BaseGameUtils is set as library and it imports the google-play-services without errors.
My test project imports the BaseGameUtils library without errors, infact if I try to import the generic library I have no error

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.*; -> no error!
```

In the folder

```
workspace\BaseGameUtils\gen\com\google\example\games\basegameutils
```

there are only two files: `BuildConfig.java` and `R.java`.
The BaseGameActivity.java file is present only in the folder

```
workspace\BaseGameUtils\java\com\google\example\games\basegameutils
```

with other two files `GameHelper.java` and `GameHelperUtils.java`.

How can I resolve the problem? A simple `Clean -> Build` has no effect.
Thank you

.: EDIT :.

[image: Here a screen of the situation]

Comment: were you able to solve this? i am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @clayton33 In your project, can you try adding BaseGameUtils to Java Build path? (Right click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add -> BaseGameUtils).

Comment: Yeah, I think I solved the issue. At the moment I can't tell you exactly what I did (I haven't my PC right now), this evening I'm going to check and I'll tell you.

Comment: I tried adding it through the java build path. I had not done this prior, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `BaseGameUtils` located at `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` instead of `BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils`. Since the `eclipse_compat` directory is no more available in the [github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) site, I've shared it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: In addition to that you also need to edit the GameHelper class of the BaseGameUtils if you are using the latest Google Play Services. Edited file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

Answer (score 1):

BaseGameActivity is not official from Google in order to use you need to copy its Source to your project. Please notice that the name of package declares its an "Example".

Comment: Ok, so why in the tutorial I've link they import the BaseGameUtils as library and than they import the BaseGameActivity as I did? I copied the entire BaseGameUtil project in my workspace as told

Comment: Read This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791228/basegame-util-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type their adding the Examples

Comment: He said only "Thanks i resolved the issue . there was another file of BaseGameUtil that i had to import" but he doesn't say which one

Comment: have u added this a library?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Infact, as I told in the post, if I use `import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.*;` I have no error but the file BaseGameActivity doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

The `eclipse_compat` folder is not directly available, it needs to be generated via a provided script. Refer to the section "If you're using Eclipse..." located on the main page of the "android-basic-samples" project.

To summarize it:

1. Download the android-basic-samples project from [GitHub](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)
2. Unpack it and navigate to the "android-basic-samples-master" folder
3. From **this** folder, run the command `Scripts/make_eclipse_compat`

Once done, follow these steps in Eclipse:

1. File -> Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace
2. Navigate to the "android-basic-samples-master\eclipse_compat\libraries" folder and select the "BaseGameUtils" folder
3. Optionally, select "Copy projects into workspace" and click Finish
4. Right click on the imported project, select Properties -> Android and select the "is Library" option
5. Within the same dialog, click the Add button to reference the "google-play-services_lib" project
6. Click OK to confirm, the project should be ready to use
7. Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android -> click the Add button to reference the imported project in your project

Answer (score 0):

It appears my issue likely is that I am using Eclipse.  I need to use the `eclipse_compat` folder and use a different `BaseGameUtils`.  However [on the github site where they host](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/issues/89) the code, they removed that folder.

They suggest using Android Studio instead, I'm just not ready to migrate there yet.  Does anyone have a copy of the `BaseGameUtils` for Eclipse?

Comment: How come the link in the question `imports gms.common.api.*;` but the asker is `importing com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;` ?

Comment: I was about to provide that suggestion, good that you figured it out. You can download the source from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: yes this worked, i needed the eclipse_compat version.  please add this as an answer instead of a comment and i will give the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `eclipse_compat` from current github.  It is generated when you run a script that comes packaged (unzip the github file, then run Scripts/`make_eclipse_compat`).

Answer (score 0):

ozbek
yes this worked,
Yeah, I think I solved the issue. (Right click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add -> BaseGameUtils).