# couldn't import BaseGameUtils properly

Tags: android, google-play-services

I a don't use Android Studio and I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405174/resolve-basegameactivity). I have downloaded the [Base Game Utils](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit) and replaced the file `BaseGameUtils\libs\android-support-v4 with android-support-v4`. I also replaced [GameHelper](https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3).

Comment: What types of error are you getting? Have you tried to "Clean Project" and "Build"?

Comment: What I did was I just copied the class files diretly as if they were part of my game. On the github, you can see the code and just copy it. Google made some changes recently and it's made it weird to implement that way.

Comment: Yes i tried Clean and build still it didn't work

Comment: here's a screenshot -https://www.dropbox.com/s/injvj8cx20jyezn/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: It says ur missing a project properties file. I think at this point u need to make a brand new project and copy over you code from the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run "make_eclipse_compat" script, located at Scripts/make_eclipse_compat in order to be able to import all of these projects using eclipse (they are created to use by Android-Studio by default).

Once you have run the script, a new folder called "eclipse_compat" will be created. You need to import the projects located at THAT folder. So, import BaseGameUtils, mark it as library and add a google_play_services as a library dependence.

Hope it helps