# How to fix this Basegame utils error?

Tags: android, import, google-play, google-play-services

We have imported "com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils" and set it as a library for our application, but it is still calling error.

```
The import
com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils cannot be resolved
```

Comment: right click on your project properties->android->library check any errors there

Comment: There are no errors :/

Comment: where did you download this library

Comment: we have downloaded this library on github

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit?usp=sharing use this. This issue is mentioned in another quetion

Comment: could you please send me a link with that mentioned question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405174/resolve-basegameactivity